# Symfony uploadedFile validator doesn't work

Tags: symfony, file-upload, validation

I want to upload some files with an input field. In my entity i receive a an uploadedFile object.

I added:

```
public static function loadValidatorMetadata(ClassMetadata $metadata)
{
  ladybug_dump("VALIDATOR");
  $metadata->addPropertyConstraint(
               'proper', new Assert\File(array(
                 'maxSize' => '1024k',
                 'mimeTypes' => array(
                   'application/pdf',
                   'application/x-pdf',),
                 'mimeTypesMessage' => 'Please upload a valid PDF',)));
}
```

I can see the VALIDATOR message but the file is ALWAYS valid.

Did i missed something ?

Edit:

I can get the error with:

```
$validator = $this->get('validator');
$errors = $validator->validate($formData);
```

How can i add the error in the Form. I want to show the error like other fields ...

Comment: Could you add your form class?

Comment: ->add("proper", "file", array('label' => false));

Answer (score 0):

Did you include following class in your class?

```
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Mapping\ClassMetadata;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;
```

Comment: Yes i did:

    use Symfony\Component\Validator\Mapping\ClassMetadata;
    use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;
    use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile as UploadedFile;